# QGIS version update files lost

Tags: qgis, shapefile, update

Today I downloaded the QGIS update (2.18.13). When I ran the .exe it asked me to uninstall the previous version, and I accepted. What I didn't realize is that many layers that I had created had the default file path of saving to the CGIS bin.

When I uninstalled the previous version, I seem to have deleted all of those files permanently.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Saving files to the QGIS bin folder is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a GIS question, so this isn't the Q&A site for it.  However, given how sick you must be feeling at the moment, I'll give you a few pointers (all of which presuppose that you haven't done anything radical on you computer since the delete - but given that you installed a new version of QGIS, your mileage may vary!):

**On Windows:**
Have a look in your trash and if you can see the relevant folder.  If it is there, you can right-click and choose 'restore' - this will kill your current installation, but could give you a chance to copy your projects some where more sensible than the QGIS bin folder.

If you can't see find the old deleted folder there you will need to get some recovery software like Recuva or Norton (other products are available).  Data is not actually scrubbed off disk when deleted. Its reference is merely deleted from the FAT or NTFS (depending on how you formatted your disk).  If you have saved other files since the delete (as you have - due to the install), expect some files to be unrecoverable - however, you may be able to get back some of your data.

**On Linux:**
Try the information [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files)

**On Mac:**
Undelete software is widely available for Macs like Windows.  I am not a Mac user so can't suggest any but a bit of research (e.g. [here](https://www.cultofmac.com/67472/how-to-undelete-files-in-mac-os-x-macrx/)) will help you.

Regardless of your operating system, it is essential that you stop using your machine until you have attempted the undelete because in all cases the space that was once used by your projects is now considered 'vacant' by the operating system and new data can and will be written over it, making it unrecoverable.

Lastly, you've learnt the hard way but never use the QGIS bin folder for storage.  Set up a decent projects nd data folder structure preferably on a different disk or partition to your operating system.